# Is there a Python library for handling and validating user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input

I have a project that involves asking for (for now, command-line) feedback from the user every so often while its main method runs.

So far I have been using `input('{my_prompt}')` to obtain this input from my user, but I have to quite annoyingly handle user input every time I invoke `input()`. This makes my code balloon to > 5 lines of code per user input line, which feels quite excessive. Some of my user input handling includes the below.

```
if input.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
    raise ValueError('Not valid input! Please enter either "y" or "n"')
if input.lower() == 'y':
    input = True
else:
    input = False
```

The above could be handled in 1 line of code if the user were passing command line arguments in and I could use `argparse`, but unfortunately the sheer volume of prompts prevents command line arguments from being a viable option.

I am familiar with the libraries [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) and [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), but as far as I can tell, they both lack the functionality that I would like from `argparse`, which is namely to validate the user input.

In summary, I'm looking for a user input library that validates input and can return `bool` values without me having to implement the conversion every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to check "yes/no" prompts, `click` supports it natively with `click.confirm`:

```py
if click.confirm("Do you want to do this thing?"):
    # ... do something here ....
```

There are a variety of other input-handling functions part of `click`, which are documented [in the User Input Prompts section](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/prompts/) of the documentation.

Comment: This is perfect--I missed this functionality when I was reading through its documentation earlier. Thanks!